# How to fix Next UI Input component label that is by default not positioning correctly when used with RTL direction?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13, nextui

I have this issue or maybe it's a bug I'm not sure with NEXT JS and Next UI, the problem is when I switch page direction to `RTL` the input label is not positioning correctly it has some sort of gap right side like the screenshot below, I did no fancy work it is just like this out of the box.

By just creating regular new Next JS project and adding Next UI support to it,

My code in `page.tsx` just for adding an input is like this:

```
  <Input 
    type="text"
    name="user" 
    label='My Lable here'
    placeholder="" 
  />
```

and in my `layout.tsx` I do direction simply like this:

```
<html lang="en" dir="rtl">
```

now the input in the rendered page looks like this:

[image]

Note that my `Input` component is the built in component within Next UI without any customization however I tried to override it like this:

```
classNames={{label: "rtl: m-0"}}
```

but it doesn't seem working...

So please how to fix this, is this a bug?

Comment: Are you creating custom Input component or using any build in package for that ?

Comment: @BhartiSharma just the regular built in package but I'm trying to go to custom just to see it there is something I can do to fix this issue but try a simple new project and u will find the problem

Comment: Yes, Try with custom Input tag and see if you still face the same issue

Comment: @BhartiSharma not working as I mentioned I'm trying to us custom to fix it, but I don't think this is the right approach

Comment: ok I found that `classNames={{label: "rtl:!-ms-4"}}` solve the problem but introduce another !

Comment: What I mean in the above comment is that was not the right solution to do, but unsuccessful workaround! Still no fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As reported in GitHub [here](https://github.com/nextui-org/nextui/issues/2315), it is a bug! So, in case someone wants to solve this, the workaround below can fix only the issue mentioned above perfectly for now.

`label: "rtl:origin-top-right" // fix for RTL bug`

I don't know if it can fix other NextUI components with RTL problem too.